# Vuelidate using Vue 2.6 and Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vuelidate

I'm using the Composition API together with Vue 2 (by using `@vue/composition-api`) combined with the following two libraries (`@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.18`,
`@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.15`).

I am trying to use `sameAs` to check whether the entered email and repeated email are a match and return an error if not. Although this is not working as smooth as expected.

This is my `validation.js` file

```
import { required, email, maxLength, sameAs } from "@vuelidate/validators";

export default {
  email: {
    required,
    email,
    maxLength: maxLength(100),
  },
  repeatEmail: {
    required,
    email,
    maxLength: maxLength(100),
    sameAsEmail: sameAs('email')
  },
}
```

and this is my `validation-errors.js` file. (probably irrelevant for this question though)

```
export default { 
  email: [
    {
      key: "required",
      message: "Email is required.",
      id: "emailRequired",
    },
    {
      key: "email",
      message: "Wrong format on your email.",
      id: "emailFormat",
    },
    {
      key: "maxLength",
      message: "Email can't be longer than 100 characters.",
      id: "emailLength",
    },
  ],
  repeatEmail: [
    {
      key: "required",
      message: "Email is required.",
      id: "emailRequired",
    },
    {
      key: "email",
      message: "Wrong format on your email.",
      id: "emailFormat",
    },
    {
      key: "maxLength",
      message: "Email can't be longer than 100 characters.",
      id: "emailLength",
    },
    {
      key: "sameAsEmail",
      message: "Email isn't matching.",
      id: "sameAsEmailFormat",
    },
  ],
}
```

And this is how I try to use it in my component.

```
import validations from "@/validation";
import validationErrors from "@/validation-errors";
import { useVuelidate } from "@vuelidate/core";
import { reactive, toRefs } from '@vue/composition-api'; 
export default {
 setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      email: "",
      repeatEmail: "",
    });
    const $v = useVuelidate(validations, state);
    return {
      ...toRefs(state)
    }
 }
}
```

So when I enter the same input in both the inputfield for email and repeatEmail correctly it gives me true as an invalid value.

Answer (score 5):

Built-in validators such as `sameAs` [don't have access to the state,](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/blob/next/packages/validators/src/raw/sameAs.js) so they aren't supposed to be workable when used like `sameAs('email')`.

This way validators are supposed to be defined in `setup` function in order to access the state:

```
 const emailRef = computed(() => state.email);
 const validations = {
   ...
   repeatEmail: {
     ...
     sameAsEmail: sameAs(emailRef)
   },
```

Otherwise this needs to be done with custom validators instead of built-ins that will access the state on component instance with `getCurrentInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use the same validation in vuejs 3 with composition syntax because using compute function get update state

```js
 code  password = computed(() => state.password);
 const validations = {
   ...
   confirm-password: {
     ...
     sameAs: sameAs(emailRef)
   },
```